# Open 2 Visio diagrams in different windows

Tags: diagram, visio

I would like to know if I can open 2 different diagrams using MS Visio and each diagram have its own window. I've tried in several ways, but I always end up with 1 Visio window ...

I'm using a triple monitor setup and I'd like to put one diagram to each side of my main monitor.

[]'s

André Casteliano

PS: I'm using Visio 2007 here.

Comment: Why was this question not migrated to Super User? There's now another question asking the same thing which actually points to and uses the correct answer from here instead. (not the accepted answer, the registry answer.) Closure brigade strikes again I guess. http://superuser.com/questions/679860/cant-open-two-instances-of-visio-2013

Comment: @MarkAllen Yeah I don't understand why so many questions get closed instead of being moved. This happens most of the time by far. It adds more noise to the SE network and waste people's time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visio 2005 allows you to open visio multiple times - does this not work in 2007?  Try opening a visio document, and then starting another instance of visio from the Start-->Programs menu.

If not, read on...

Visio is an MDI interface - you'll need to stretch the whole visio window across the two monitors in question, then choose the "Window" menu and select "Tile" after you've opened your two documents.

Alternately, in the upper right hand corner just below the application minimize, restore and close buttons you'll find the document minimize, restore and close.  Choose restore, and you can manipulate the windows inside the main visio app.

Hope this helps!

-Adam Davis

Answer (score 39):

This allows you to open two or more instances of Visio so that you can view different Visio docs at the same time without going through the process to stretch the Visio window across two screens. I found this to be a simpler method and a bit easier to manipulate. If it doesn't work on your first try recheck the registry setting. It changed back on me a couple of times before it took.

To implement the new behaviour, follow the following registry trick:

1. Open Microsoft Visio.
2. Go to `Tools -> Options -> Advanced` or `File -> Options -> Advanced` in newer versions.
3. Check the Put all settings in Windows Registry option.
4. Close Microsoft Visio
5. Run Registry Editor (regedit).
6. Navigate to the following registry key:

   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Visio\Application\`
   **Note:** The value `12.0` in the key can be different.
   (i.e: for Visio 2010: `14.0`, Visio 2019: `16.0`)
7. In the right pane, right click on `SingleInstanceFileOpen`, and then select Modify. Update the value of `SingleInstanceFileOpen` from `1` to `0`

**If the value `SingleInstanceFileOpen` doesn't exist**, it can be created as a type REG_SZ.

Comment: Just to add to @J-D answer, you need to make sure that all Visio instances are closed 'before' making the registry change otherwise it will revert to the original setting.

Comment: For extra info, in Visio 2013 the key (SingleInstanceFileOpen) now defaults to 0

Comment: I'd like to add that using `CTRL + N` for a new instance is not affected by this and will always use the same instance you pressed the shotcut on while still showing 2 different instances in the taskbar. Also explicitely opening a second instance (i.e. using the taskbar -> `Right click Visio -> Visio`) will work even without the registry change.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like my installation of Visio is the problem. I've tried on another computer here and it allow me to open 2 instances of the software.